# NSString from NSData returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsstring, nsdata

So I am using Parse (which is pretty sweet) and I'm in the process of downloading files (short video files - no more then 1mb) from the parse server to my application to play. Now the way it works is (via documentation)..

```
PFFile* videoFile = [[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"track"];


[videoFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
       if (!error) {
           NSString* dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
           NSURL* videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:dataString];
           // now do something with this videoURL (i.e. play it!)
           [data writeToFile:@"trackFile" atomically:YES];
                NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"trackFile"];
                NSLog(@"File Path: %@",filePath);

                AVAsset* asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:filePath];
                AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];

       }
}
```

On download completion you are suppossed to create a string from the data and then a url from the string. Only problem is  - the dataString always returns NULL/nil. I have confirmed that the data property is not empty and does in fact hold the video data. Why is this happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> I have confirmed that the data property is not empty and does in fact hold the video data.

Video data is not a UTF-8 string. It's definitely not a UTF-8 string representation of an URL. So when you say "interpret this video data as UTF-8," Cocoa rightly responds that it is not UTF-8 (because it's video data).

The simplest solution is to write this to disk, and then play the file.

Comment: Thanks for this insight. By writing to disk will this hold the video file on the device forever? What I am looking to accomplish is something very similar to Instagram's video playing. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any simple way to hand raw data to an `AVPlayer`. It really wants the data in a local or remote URL. You are responsible for cleaning up files you create. Just delete them when you finish with them, and delete all your temp files when you launch.

Comment: Do search SO for "avplayer nsdata." This has been discussed many times over the years.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things that need to be determined first:

1. does the NSData object actually have any data, i.e., data.length > 0?
2. does the NSData object hold video data *OR* the url of the video data (not exactly clear)?

Making the assumption that the NSData object is holding the url and it's length is greater than 0, then you might want to try:

```
NSString* dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: The NSData object does have data. How can I tell if the NSData object holds video data or rather the url of the video data. (I'm pretty sure it holds the video data though)..Nonetheless,  I've tried with NSASCIIStringEncoding and it still returned nil

Comment: What's the length of the NSData? If its only a couple hundred characters, then probably a url. If it's MB big, then probably video data.

Comment: Video data!! So save it to disk and play the file...and then mark the file (and any others) for deletion later on (so you don't fill up your disk).

Comment: Okay. Do you think this is how Instagram does it with the videos you see in posts?

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea how Instagram does it... never used instagram. How long you hold on to video files is really up to you and is a usability decision (i.e., will your users be coming back and re-watching this, and if so, probably keep it around for awhile).

Comment: please see updated answer - your solution doesn't seem to be working